# Error- A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: 'products. Value: {"_x":0"_y",_z":null,"_A":null}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I am basically trying to save the state of like/dislike on list of products which I am trying to fetch from an API using axios, but I'm getting the below error.

> A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path:
> 'products. Value: {"_x":0"_y",_z":null,"_A":null}

To save the state, I am trying to use Redux Toolkit. Below I have codes for `productSlice` component and `ProductListScreen` component.

productSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: { items: [], likes: [] },
  reducers: {
    fetchProducts: async (state) => {
      const response = await axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products");
      state.items = response.data;
      state.likes = new Array(state.items.length).fill(false);
    },
    toggleLike: (state, action) => {
      state.likes[action.payload.index] = action.payload.isLiked;
    },
  },
});

export const { fetchProducts, toggleLike } = productsSlice.actions;

export default productsSlice.reducer;
```

productListScreen.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchProducts, toggleLike } from "./productsSlice";

const ProductListScreen = () => {
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.items);
  const likes = useSelector((state) => state.products.likes);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, []);

  const handleLike = (index, isLiked) => {
    dispatch(toggleLike({ index, isLiked }));
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <LikeDislikeButton
        productId={item.id}
        liked={likes[index]}
        onPress={() => handleLike(index, !likes[index])}
      />
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={products}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductListScreen;
```

Answer (score 5):

Reducer functions are supposed to be pure ***synchronous*** functions. You have declared the `fetchProducts` reducer function `async` which *implicitly* returns a Promise object. This is the non-serializable object that is stored into `state.products`.

You should be creating and using an asynchronous action, i.e. a Thunk, to make asynchronous API calls. Refactor `fetchProducts` to be an asynchronous action. Use the `productSlice`'s `extraReducers` to handle the fulfilled Promise returned from the `fetchProducts` thunk.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/fetchProducts",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products");
    return response.data;
  },
);

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: { items: [], likes: [] },
  reducers: {
    toggleLike: (state, action) => {
      state.likes[action.payload.index] = action.payload.isLiked;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { products } = action.payload;
        state.items = products;
        state.likes = new Array(products.length).fill(false);
      });
  },
});

export const { toggleLike } = productsSlice.actions;

export default productsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, that really helped. I can now display a list of products with like button below each one. But pressing on a like button prompts an error saying- "Immer only supports array indices and the 'length' property".

Comment: @PiyushChatterjee That's a bit off-topic from this post's subject. Since the action is called `toggleLike` what if you only `dispatch(toggleLike({ index }));` and then in the reducer case did `state.likes[action.payload.index] = !state.likes[action.payload.index];`? If not this, think you could create a small [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code (*using a react-native template OFC*) that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @PiyushChatterjee What you have *looks* ok, so having a running example to dig in on would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`response.data` is the object that contains the list of products.

```
{"products":[{"id":1,"title":"iPhone 9",...}]}
```

```
const response = await axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products");
state.items = response.data.products;
```

Comment: It still gives the same error, even after correcting it to:
```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: 'products. Value: {"_x":0"_y",_z":null,"_A":null
```